# Has the Twitter search syntax silently changed?

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

So for the last few weeks I've been performing the following search:

```
#MyHashTag filter:images
```

And it has worked perfectly. Until yesterday/today when it stopped and displays zero results. Additional tests show:

```
Trump
```

works, but

```
Trump filter:images
```

does not. This is with a software query to the API, twitter.com and Tweetdeck.

Have they revoked this filtering option?

Comment: Maybe a temporary issue? I just searched `#MyHashTag filter:images` on Twitter.com and it returned many results.

Comment: Seems you're correct, back functioning again. - You can answer the q to get the credit if you like.

Comment: Glad it's working. Always good to have an answer for when other people search with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a temporary issue. I searched `#MyHashTag filter:images` on Twitter.com and it returned many results.